# Passing wildcard * to a (bash?) script

Tags: shell-script, quoting, wildcards

I want to to remove all color codes which look like '@n', '@R' etc, from a moderately large size collection of text files.

So in a file called 'remove_cc', I wrote the following:

```
sed -ie 's/@r//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@g//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@y//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@b//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@m//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@c//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@n//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@R//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@G//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@Y//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@B//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@M//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@C//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@N//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@W//g' $1
sed -ie 's/@K//g' $1
```

Anyways, the script works fantastically if I use it like:
./remove_cc file.txt

But if I type `./remove_cc *.txt` in a folder with many txt files that I want to run the script on, it fails to do anything.  `./remove_cc *` is equally ineffective.

Is there a way to fix this so it works?

Comment: Just a short note: `-i` is not specified by POSIX, so you *may* encounter `sed`s that won't understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type `./remove_cc *`, the shell changes it to `./remove_cc file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt etc`, and runs your script that way.  Your script is only looking at `$1`, the first parameter (file1.txt).

The most general way to do this is to loop over each parameter in turn.  `"$@"` expands to the list of all the parameters, and we can use `for` to loop over them.

```
for n in "$@" ; do
    sed -ie 's/@r//g' "$n"
    ...
done
```

In this particular case, since `sed` will take multiple filenames, you can simplify:

```
sed -ie 's/@r//g' "$@"
```

Note that paying attention to quotes is important when writing shell scripts.  Without the quotes, for example, the script would not work on a file named `My Text File.txt`.

Answer (score 8):

just use

```
 for x in *
 do
     ./remove_cc $x
 done
```

By the way, you can combine all sed in one line

```
sed -i \
    -e 's/@r//g' -e 's/@g//g' -e 's/@y//g' -e 's/@b//g' \
    -e 's/@m//g' -e 's/@c//g' -e 's/@n//g' -e 's/@R//g' \
    -e 's/@G//g' -e 's/@Y//g' -e 's/@B//g' -e 's/@M//g' \
    -e 's/@C//g' -e 's/@N//g' -e 's/@W//g' -e 's/@K//g' \
    $1
```

you can also join sed commands with semicolons:

```
sed -i -e 's/@r//g;s/@g//g;s/@y//g' $1
```

or just use character list

```
sed -i -e s/@[rgbcmyRGBCMY]//g $1
```

or

```
 sed -i -e s/@[rgbcmyRGBCMY]//g *
```

(be sure to check I have put all the letter)

Answer (score 1):

Use `"$@"` instead of `$1`. Or quote the wildcard:

```
$ bash -c 'echo $1' 'some command' '*'
file1 file2
$ bash -c 'echo "$@"' 'some command' *
file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to change your script you can also use xargs (considering you have it or it's available on your platform) by running it like this:

`ls *.txt | xargs -L1 ./remove_cc`

xargs is a utility that takes stdin and transforms it to command parameters on a command to be run. It has the -L flag that limits the amount of input lines to be used in a single execution.

Comment: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)